# What does "from 30% off" mean?

Tags: meaning, mathematics

> "Shop everything you need for fashion - from 30% off"

This is a banner. Does "from 30% off" mean the discount rate starts from 30%?
Or does this mean "products from 30% off", which means products with 30% discounted price?

Comment: Curious how you reached to the number 50 from 30

Comment: I would understand that to mean that everything is discounted by at least 30% - at least, that's what the words mean. If it's a sign in questionable English that has been put up to get me to go into the shop, it could mean anything, quite possibly *some things in here are discounted by 30%*.

Comment: @Minty, you should turn this comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advertisements, especially the ones for discounts, are usually made to be misleading, tricking the honest customer's mind.

Have in mind the usual:

> Discounts up to 80%!!

What does that mean? That you can buy anything for 80% discount? Form my experience, it always means that there is a piece of rag with a discount of 80%, and everything else is pretty much not discounted. Or discounted 2%-5%.

---

Therefore, this:

> "Shop everything you need for fashion - from 30% off"

can mean anything that the shop wants it to mean.

Comment: Yes, I'd say it was almost purposefully vague. It should mean the opposite of *up to 30% off* but it doesn't where it goes *to* after going *from*. Consider it could mean *from 30% off to full price*